# Join Files in Unix /Java using Wildcard columns

Tags: java, unix, join, awk, wildcard

How to join two files in Unix with wildcards and no key column?

In SQL we can do :

```
Select T1.Col1, T2.Col_Group, T2.Priority
from table1 T1
join table2 T2
where T1.Col1 like %T2.Col1%
```

how do we achieve the same in Unix/Java? I have joined two files using AWK when we have key using array. But how do we do it when there is no Key?

Say, File1 has few million recs:

```
ID Col1 Col2
101  ABCD IJKL
201  ABCD IJKL
301  ADBC JKLM
```

File2 has 2 recs:

```
Priority Col1 Col2 GROUP
1        ABC* IJKL G1
2        A*   I*   G2
```

Output (lowest priority):

```
ID   Col1 Col2  GROUP 
101  ABCD IJKL  G1
201  ABCD IJKL  G1
301  ADBC JKLM  NULL
```

Comment: Please add more details: files are not databases, you can't do "joins" on them. Are you by chance working with CSV files or similar?

Comment: `man join` on any Unix/Linux will solve your stated problem. Read about the `-e` and `-o` options and look at the examples near the end of the file. AND literallly thousands of QA here if you search for `[linux] join` or [unix] join`. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yes Andrea we are using pipe delimiter. Shelter, I tried join   and applied sort but it does not do the trick.